# Entering Schengen zone as a tourist before my working permit starts (Sweden)

Tags: schengen, sweden

I'll soon be working on Stockholm. I already have my work and residence permit approved starting on September 17th.

However, I have plans to visit a friend over in Barcelona first (around September 2nd). I have a visa-free entry to Schengen as a tourist (since I have a Chilean passport).

Can I enter the Schengen zone as a tourist first, and then moving over Stockholm to start working after the permit date or do I need to re-enter to activate the work permit?

The relocation agency that is helping me with this process mentioned that there's no problem about it, but the only thing I should consider is that I can't start working before the 17th. I just want to confirm this before buying the plane tickets.

Thanks!